# Rails + POST Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the curb gem (https://github.com/taf2/curb) to create an HTTP POST request with the  `name` value. My curb request looks like this:

```
http = Curl.post("http://localhost:3001/campaigns", {:name => "Facebook"})
```

This gets sent to a rails API but the method in the API is expecting a hash. I then want to apply Strong Parameters (using the code below). How can I modify my POST request to send a hash called campaign with name as one attribute?

```
private
def campaign_params
    params.require(:campaign).permit(:name)
end
```

Thanks

Comment: `http = Curl.post("http://localhost:3001/campaigns", {campaign: {name: 'Facebook'}}`

Comment: You're missing a bracket in your code but it still doesn't work. `NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "{:name=>\"Facebook\"}":String):`

Comment: huh..try `{"campaign[name]" => "Facebook"}`

Comment: Cool that's sorted it - if you want to put this as an answer I will tick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http = Curl.post("http://localhost:3001/campaigns", {"campaign[name]" => "Facebook"})
```